# Defining your own cursor not working in IE 8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cursor

this page works perfectly in Firefox and chrome but not in IE :

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" > 
      body{ 
        cursor: url("crosshair2nosprinkles.cur") 24 24, default;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does it do in IE? Does it not change the cursor? Is the cursor not visible?

Comment: the cursor is the default arrow one and doesn't change

Comment: Try dropping the `"` (quotes) around the url. They are optional anyway and IE8 might not like them.

Comment: i did and no effect... why did i get downvoted???

Comment: where can i validate it?

Comment: i also used <!DOCTYPE html> at the beginning.... NOTHING

Comment: If you remove `24 24` does it work ?

Comment: Are there any 404 errors when trying to load the cursor in IE, but not in other browsers?

Comment: i removed the 24 24 but nothing yet

Comment: I tried in IE8 and it seems to work when I only specify the url part, drop the numbers and default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer was that IE didn't accept hotspot coords so i had to make myself a cursor with implicit hotspots and also i had to define the DOCTYPE at the beginning of the page

Answer (score 4):

`.cur` files have the hotspot built-in, so you don't need to specify it explicitly. Try this:

```
cursor: url("crosshair2nosprinkles.cur"), default;
```

If that doesn't work properly, make sure the cursor filehas the hotspot correctly defined.

Comment: hey.. i've tried removing the hotspot coords but it still doesn't work... i think i'll try downloading a .cur file and see if there is a problem with mine

Comment: okay... so I've downloaded this cursor http://www.rw-designer.com/cursor-detail/42281 and used it instead..... it STILL doesn't work

Comment: @user783476 Drop the `default` part.

Comment: @Kolink Then use conditionals and double defining or something, I couldn't get it to work in IE8 unless it didn't have the default bit.

Answer (score 2):

Custom cursor syntax is a little weird cross-browser. See the blog post *[Cross-browser custom CSS cursors](https://beradrian.wordpress.com/2008/01/08/cross-browser-custom-css-cursors/)* for the quirks, and so you can figure out which ones you need to implement for whichever browsers you want to support.

Without seeing paths, or the full HTML code (because I assume you simplified the above), it might problems with your URL reference, since IE bases the cursor relative paths not on the location of the CSS, like most `url()` uses, but by the source element. Are you getting any 404 errors in some browsers but not others? The linked guide should be able to walk you through how to fix it. (Or you can give us more details from the code including paths, network requests and statuses, a live example link, etc. and we can help you.)

Comment: thank you, i've already read that link but my problem isn't relative path-related bc i have the style in the same file as the html... anyway i have simplified the code in order to isolate the problem but to no avail up to now